# SQL Server Parsing

Tags: sql-server

I have data in one column as below semi colon delimited.  I want to parse this in separate rows.

9000389003; 9000389000; 9000389093; 9000383895; 9000490984; 9000389000
9000490980; 9000593580; 9000593599; 9000498085; 9000389003; 9000593580; 9000490990
9000489405; 9000435334; 9000535090; 9000995990

Comment: Are you going to show us what you attempted and found to not work?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614343, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075137, and many others

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
create table t (id int not null identity(1,1), str varchar(8000));
insert into t values 
  ('9000389003; 9000389000; 9000389093; 9000383895; 9000490984; 9000389000')
 ,('9000490980; 9000593580; 9000593599; 9000498085; 9000389003; 9000593580; 9000490990') 
 ,('9000489405; 9000435334; 9000535090; 9000995990');

select 
    t.id
  , s.ItemNumber
  , Item = ltrim(s.Item)
from t
  cross apply [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](t.str,';') as s
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/AVQL94047

returns:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | ItemNumber |    Item    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | 9000389003 |
|  1 |          2 | 9000389000 |
|  1 |          3 | 9000389093 |
|  1 |          4 | 9000383895 |
|  1 |          5 | 9000490984 |
|  1 |          6 | 9000389000 |
|  2 |          1 | 9000490980 |
|  2 |          2 | 9000593580 |
|  2 |          3 | 9000593599 |
|  2 |          4 | 9000498085 |
|  2 |          5 | 9000389003 |
|  2 |          6 | 9000593580 |
|  2 |          7 | 9000490990 |
|  3 |          1 | 9000489405 |
|  3 |          2 | 9000435334 |
|  3 |          3 | 9000535090 |
|  3 |          4 | 9000995990 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use SQL-Server 2016 for `string_split()` or if you are not allowed to create a new function, or if you just want a simpe ad-hoc approach you might do it this way:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id int not null identity, YourString varchar(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
  ('9000389003; 9000389000; 9000389093; 9000383895; 9000490984; 9000389000')
 ,('9000490980; 9000593580; 9000593599; 9000498085; 9000389003; 9000593580; 9000490990') 
 ,('9000489405; 9000435334; 9000535090; 9000995990');

 WITH Casted AS
 (
    SELECT t.id 
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourString,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AsXml
    FROM @tbl AS t
 )
 SELECT id
       ,nodes.value('(./text())[1]','bigint') AS TheNumber
 FROM Casted
 CROSS APPLY Casted.AsXml.nodes('/x') AS The(nodes)
```

One advantage might be - other than usual string splitter approaches - that you get the values typed (as `bigint` in this case).